# Ecto Postgres install error password authentication failed

Tags: postgresql, phoenix-framework, ecto

I created a phoenix project from the hello example using digital ocean.  I entered the username and password from the etc/motd.tail file.  I keep getting the error message below.  I am a beginner and for some reason I just cannot get ecto to install correctly.

** (Mix) The database for Hello.Repo couldn't be created, reason given: psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "elixir"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "elixir"

You can use the following Postgress database credentials:
  * User: elixir
  * Pass:  ***

install.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume this error is happening on the `mix ecto.create` task?

This happens because Ecto uses `psql` to create the database, however this is no longer the case in the upcoming Ecto 2.0.

The following GitHub issue shows the same issue https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/issues/1207

The relevant comment with the fix is https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/issues/1207#issuecomment-172570064:

> My database config (pg_hba.conf) was apparently wrong.
>
> For anyone else encountering this:
>
> host all my_user 127.0.0.1/32 trust will not work
>   host all my_user localhost trust will work

Please check your `pg_hba.conf` (likely in `/etc/postsgresql/9.x/pg_hba.conf`).

Comment: First thank you for your help.

I attempted to edit my pg_hba.conf file (localhost trust).

host    all             all             localhost trust        md5

** (Mix) The database for Hello.Repo couldn't be created, reason given: psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: I just created a new phoenix project in root and then ran mix ecto.create and it worked.  Thank you

Answer (score 97):

I get the same error using Ubuntu 14.04 and I corrected resetting the 'postgres' password:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'postgres';"
```

and restart postgres service:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Comment: Worked for me too!

Answer (score 3):

We just need to create a new postgresql `username` and `password` according to the files inside `config` folder using [this db method](https://medium.com/coding-blocks/creating-user-database-and-adding-access-on-postgresql-8bfcd2f4a91e)

```
$ sudo -u postgres createuser <username>
$ sudo -u postgres createdb <dbname>
$ sudo -u postgres psql
psql=# alter user <username> with encrypted password '<password>';
psql=# grant all privileges on database <dbname> to <username> ;
```

Comment: `✗ sudo -u postgres createuser me
sudo: unknown user: postgres
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update the pg_hba.conf to make this work.

I am using Fedora, so get to /var/lib/pgsql/data

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
```

Then I created an elixir user in postgres with databse creation capabilities and configured it in dev.exs (user/password/database)